# How to get rid of the white vertical stroke after every repeating background image done with repeat-x value in CSS?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, background-repeat

Not really sure why this happens, but if I set my body background image a value of repeat-x, it repeats fine, but adds this white stroke after every repeated image. Can someone tell me why this is? I have never come across this before. Below you can see my CSS.

```
body {
font-family: Verdana, Helvetica;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url("themes/base/images/tausta2.png") repeat-x;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: can you show your image & code for better understanding

Comment: your css looks fine, must be smth. else. Did you check your image for an unwanted stroke?

Comment: http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/6993820/1024/Anonymous/tausta2.png This is the image i am repeating

Comment: and this is how it looks like on the website: http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/6993828/1024/Anonymous/screen4.png

Comment: The issue is with your image, there's a gradient and the left side is clearly much lighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your source image. This has a second gradient (top-bottom as well as left-right) in it, if you look closely:

[image: gradient]

Comment: this is not CSS problem. white strokes from ur image

Comment: Yes, that is what happens when you repeat it. I edited my answer to stipulate that you have two gradients (e.g. in two ways). You should only have the top-bottom gradient. The left-right gradient causes the effect of the white stroke.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

ur image gradient more white al left and more dark at right

use 1px width background image to correct this mistake:

[image]